# Handwriting vs $\LaTeX$

Tags: proof-writing, soft-question, learning

Until a few months ago, I would handwrite practically all the math I wrote. However, I've been using LaTeX to typeset notes, assignments, etc quite extensively since then - to the point that I've started noticing that I'm only able to absorb the material fully once I type it up now. Even if I'm reading up notes and then writing proofs down by hand, I feel like I only gain a full understanding of them after typing them up. Is that something that others experience? Is this a bad sign, since I suppose handwriting math is still a more efficient way of learning (rather than typing everything)?

Comment: Is there anything I can edit in this post/add to it to prevent it from being closed?

Comment: To the people who voted to close - how is this seeking personal advice? There are several posts on this website about different methods of learning math; I don't see how this is different from any of them.

Comment: I don't agree that this question should be closed. It's clearly tagged under soft-question and learning. Nothing about this question seems to be out of those bounds...

Comment: I have the same concern, and unfortunately, it is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I've certainly felt this, as well. I'm an undergrad math major and started typing up homework and notes over the last year or so. I had similar concerns, so my solution was to write up the entirety of my homeworks and notes *extremely* clearly before going to type it up in LaTeX. At first, I tended to write plenty of equations on paper and then fill in textual details when typing; as I'm sure you know, typing it up often requires more context. I found that filling in the details by hand (sometimes excessively) quashed this concern for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to learn $\LaTeX$, especially as an undergraduate mathematics major. While writing proofs, I prefer to write my initial attempts on paper before formally writing up the proof in an [Overleaf](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJ_9_dnYbpAhUaVc0KHSGGD7oQFjAAegQICRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.overleaf.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw02MN5sJbAaTyjdRNXsJYWE) document. I typically write two or three drafts on paper before combining all of my ideas into a single Overleaf document.

This strategy has gotten me through all of my mathematics courses (including the prelim/qualifying exams, which I took last year). However, I still do handwrite all of my course notes. This is because I haven't found an efficient way to type up lecture notes at the same pace that the lecturer writes material on a chalkboard. A bunch of students can type up lecture notes in class and listen to the lecture, but I prefer to handwrite my notes and then later type up a $\LaTeX$ document.

In general, I would recommend doing all of the mathematics on pencil and paper before worrying about a $\LaTeX$ document. My strategy is to purchase a bunch of Mead spiral notebooks which contain $70$-$100$ sheets of lined paper. I typically go through about $1$-$2$ notebooks a week. In the notebooks, I summarize all of the course notes and I also try to write every proof that I read in my own words. When one of the proofs is complete, I make an Overleaf document and fill in the details.

Learning $\LaTeX$ will also be beneficial later in life. You could create a personal website and add all of your lecture notes under a course notes subsection. Also, if you are interested in publishing some of your work then it will be easier to write your first publication if you are familiar with $\LaTeX$.